# Additional drivers not showing anything

Tags: drivers, 16.04, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion Laptop running AMD Radeon driver but when I go to "additional drivers" on my Ubuntu 16.04 I don't see anything, it is completely blank.

Am I missing something here and should more drivers be showing ?

Thanks W

Comment: Why do you think something should show, or that you miss anything?

Comment: Just wondering if something was missing as an am also running BricsCAD and BricsCAD says that no driver is installed ( and the display  when working with dimensions are all OVER the place).. which got me thinking that something may be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and should more drivers be showing ?

No; but it depends on your hardware. The general 2 are video card and in some instances there is also one for your NIC (if you do not have a broadcom... nothing will show).

> Am I missing something here

Well. There is NO 16.04 AMD 3rd party driver so that one will not show up. Your NIC is probably a native one too.

- [more info](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04):

> If you use the AMD Catalyst (fglrx) driver on Ubuntu you may wish to avoid upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS next month.
>
> The ‘Xenial Xerus’ will not support the widely used — and widely hated — proprietary graphics driver for AMD/ATI graphics cards.
>
> Instead, Ubuntu “recommend[s using] open source alternatives (radeon and amdgpu)”, and say “AMD put a lot of work into the[se] drivers, and we back ported kernel code from Linux 4.5 to provide a better experience.”

Tip: Do make sure you did an update after installation.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering if something was missing as an am also running BricsCAD and BricsCAD says that no driver is installed ( and the display  when working with dimensions are all over the place)